# Android os storage

Tags: storage, operating-system

My android OS is using up over 4GB of my internal storage. How do I decrease the amount of GB its using to free up some space. None of other things are using that much storage. I've backed up my stuff on Verizon cloud and deleted pictures. That freed up some space but again the OS is using way more storage than it used to and more than anything else. I have a Motorola Razr hd.

Answer (score 1):

Have you got lots of bloatware on your phone? (e.g apps preloaded on there by the carrier you bought it from). If so, and if it is bugging you enough to possibly void your warranty, you might want to try flashing a AOSP Rom such as Cyanogenmod which doesn't come with bloatware.
If you're not into trying that, try a cache cleaner app.

Good luck